# How to force browser to load new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, browser

I'm having a problem with my browser (both Chrome on my laptop and chrome on my smartphone).
I'm developing a website page (HTML, javascript) and I noticed that my browser always retrieve the cached information without loading the page each time so I'm not able to see the changes I make in the code.

In order to see the changes, I always have to clear web data and clear the browser cache.
I alread checked the settings on both browsers, but everything seems to be OK.

I added these lines, but the problem is still there.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: By content you mean static files (JS, CSS, ...)? or HTML?

Comment: both JS and HTML

Answer (score 1):

***Client-side Technique***

Force a new version into the browser, you can always add a query string to the request, and bump up the version number when you make major changes:

```
 <script src="/myJavascript.js?version=4"></script>      <-- Version Number add each time
```

This will ensure that everyone gets the new file. It works because the browser looks at the URL of the file to determine whether it has a copy in cache. If your server isn't set up to do anything with the query string, it will be ignored, but the name will look like a new file to the browser.

***Development-side Technique***

On the other hand, if you're developing a website, you don't want to change the version number every time you save a change to your development version.

So while you're developing your site, a good trick would be to automatically generate a query string parameter:

```
<!-- Development version: -->

<script>document.write('<script src="/myJavascript.js?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

It will generate query string for you each time!

Comment: what I need to write inside myJavascript.js?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet you have to replace that  -->  /myjavascript.js  <-- with your own js file name. While math floor will help to develop a random number each time so when you save your work it will not chached it will be treated as a new version.

Comment: I will try this solution and let you know if it works! Thank you!